# Dynamic meta tag not being displayed on fb sharing debugger

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meta-tags

I am currently implementing dynamic metatag for social share preview using react served by express. I am following this project:

https://github.com/justswim/cra-metatag-demo

controller part:

```
app.get('/item/:itemId/about', function(request, response) {
  const id = request.params.itemId;
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './build', 'index.html')
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, 'Contact Page');
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, "Contact page description");
    result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, `https://i.imgur.com/${id}/img`);
    response.send(result);
  });
});
```

index.html from build folder of react:

```
<title>THE NAME</title>
<meta name="title" content="Meta Tags">
<meta name="description" content="There are some contents here">

<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->

    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://[NAME_OF_SITE]">
    <meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE">
    <meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION">
    <meta property="og:image" content="$OG_IMAGE">
    
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://...">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="$OG_TITLE">
    <meta property="twitter:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="$OG_IMAGE">
```

I added the above code snippet and deployed to the server and tested out. The dynamic links work well on discord, but testing on the site social share preview, https://socialsharepreview.com/, the site says og:image property could not be found although i have added it. I need to refresh once and the site finds the property og:url, the image loads but i get the warning, the image is not optimal. testing on sharing debugger from Fb, the title description and image url are updated and it says, invalid url for image and the title and description remains as OG_TITLE and OG_DESCRIPTION. what is going on here? On viewing the page source from my webapp, everything is properly updated though.

Comment: Is it just the socialsharepreview website that isn't working? What is your deployed link so I can check myself?

Answer (score 0):

The following...

```
result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, 'https://i.imgur.com/${id}/img');
```

...should be changed to:

```
result = data.replace(/\$OG_IMAGE/g, `https://i.imgur.com/${id}/img`);
```

As in, change the single quotes to backticks in the image url.

This might explain why the image wasn't getting picked up. However, I'm not sure why the title and description aren't getting picked up either.

Comment: i have backticks in the image url when deploying. i accidentally added the quotes here.

Comment: @Nothing Ok, well I can't find out any other reason why it isn't working